# How Can I capture the event before my App is minimized?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need to close some resources  I am using when the App is minimized by clicking on Home Button.

Attention, I don't want to intercept the Home button, I know it is not allowed by Apple

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the delegate method `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` which is in appdelegate class. Whenever user taps the home button, this method will be called. for more details, [check apple documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground:) You can use `applicationWillResignActive:` in case you want to detect an incoming phone call or sms as well along with app minimizing.

Comment: This is about **cocoa** (Mac OSX), not **cocoa-touch** (iOS)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII What is?  This answer is valid for cocoa touch, and the linked documentation is iOS.  The question is also about cocoa touch.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I dont understand the downvote, delete flag and comment. As far as I can see the question was all about iphone and iOS(tags says it) and the home button part clearly indicates that it is an iphone home button. Then how in the world it can be a cocoa question? Only possibility is that Edwin might have wrongly put cocoa instead of cocoa touch but you should have checked other tags.

Comment: This question was retagged for cocoa touch after being tagged as cocoa. A misunderstanding.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, Thanks. Saw that just now.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at the `UIApplicationDelegate` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)). Specifically, `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` should be what you want.

From the Apple docs, [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW35) also goes into more detail with examples - App States and Multitasking.